# Compare strings, coefficients

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a sheet with multiple parameters tied to multiple coefficients.
I have parameter in left side and parameter in the right side.

How to make so that on the SAME LINE, the coefficients of the same parameter appear (the parameters of the right side will then be the same as that of the left side on the same line). If a parameter on the left does not appear on the right, then leave a blank space on the right. I also have, for certain parameters, several coefficients.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TICvN.jpg)

Comment: Do you start with coefficients in A:C, something generates coefficients in E:G? Now you want to filter E:G for only matches with A?

Comment: Try examples.  Your explanation is about as clear as mud

Comment: Actually, I have something that generates coefficients in E:G and I want to "replace" them, I found it more simple to explain this way..

Comment: Is it always if there are 3 matching coeeficients on the left there are 3 on the right?

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

The following example uses the coefficients in column A and filter out all matching coefficients from column E:G.  It also arranges them into the same row.

**Script**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
    let sheetLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    // Get range of A:C
    let coef1 = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheetLastRow,3);
    let lastRow = coef1.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    coef1 = coef1.getValues();
    if( lastRow < sheetLastRow ) coef1 = coef1.slice(0,lastRow);
    // Put headers in result array
    let result = [coef1.shift()];
    // Get range of E:G
    let coef2 = sheet.getRange(1,5,sheetLastRow,3);
    lastRow = coef2.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    coef2 = coef2.getValues();
    if( lastRow < sheetLastRow ) coef2 = coef2.slice(0,lastRow);
    // Remove headers
    coef2.shift();
    // Find unique coef numbers
    let coef = [...new Set( coef1.map( row => row[0] ) )];
    // Filter all elements from E:G matching A:C
    coef.forEach( c => {
      let match = coef2.filter( row => row[0] === c );
      if( match.length === 0 ) {
        result.push(['','','']);
      }
      else {
        result = result.concat(match);
      }
    });
    //  For now put in I:K
    sheet.getRange(1,9,result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Screen shot**

[image]

**Reference**

- [Range.getNextDataCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction))
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)
- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)